# error: invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*

Tags: c++, string, char

In the following code

```
#include <stdlib.h> //atoi
#include <string>   

using namespace std;

namespace roman
{
    string convert( int input )
    {
        string inputStr = to_string(input);
        if(inputStr.size()==4)
        {
            return string( atoi( inputStr[0] ), 'M')+convert(stoi(inputStr.substr(1, npos)));//error here
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the titular error in the `return` line. I think it has something to to with the atoi function. It takes a `const char*` as the input value. I need to know how to turn the first character in `inputStr` into a `const char*`. I tried appending `.c_str()` to the end of `inputStr[0]`, but that gave me the error `request for member c_str which is of non-class type char`. Anyone have some ideas?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Get a [good book on C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) on C++ and _read_ it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`inputStr[0]` is a char (the first char of `inputStr`); `atoi` wants a pointer to a null-terminated sequence of chars.

You need `inputStr.c_str()`.

EDIT: If you really want just the first character and not the whole string then `inputStr.substr(0, 1).c_str()` would do the job.

Comment: Rather than `substr`, just `inputStr[0] - '0'` will convert a single digit to its numeric value.

Answer (score 0):

You are indexing

```
inputStr[0]
```

to get at a single character. This is not a string and atoi() cannot digest it.

Try constructing a string of one character and call atoi() with that.

Something like,

```
atoi( string(1, inputStr[0]) );
```

might work. But, that is not the only or best way as it creates a temporary string and throws it away.

But, it will get you going.

Comment: It appears that you want to do atoi() on the entire string. If so, the previous answer should work fine.